# Writing pdf data into csv

Tags: python, csv, pdf, pdfminer

I am a beginner to python and I am stuck in a critical part of my script. The goal is to get fillable pdf data into one single csv file. I have built a script to do so through pdfminer but I am now stuck in the part where I should get my script to write all of the output data into my csv. Instead, I am only getting one data line written in my csv. Any clue please?

Here is my code:

```
import sys, os
import six
import csv
import numpy as np
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

fp = open("C:\\Users\\Sufyan\\Desktop\\test\\ccc.pdf", "rb")

parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
fields = resolve1(doc.catalog["AcroForm"])["Fields"]
for i in fields:
    field = resolve1(i)
    name, value = field.get("T"), field.get("V")
    filehehe = "{0}:{1}".format(name,value)
    values = resolve1(value)
    names = resolve1(name)
    print(values)


with open('test.csv','wb') as f: 
    for i in names: 
        f.write(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clues:

1. There is no `i` inside this loop:

```py
with open('test.csv','wb') as f: 
    for i in names: 
        f.write(values)
```

2. For the same `for` loop, which values does `names` contain? Are these a lot? 1? 2? Why?